# How to return list for a Python 3.6 filter function?

Tags: python, list, token

I defined a function to remove characters from a list of tokens:

```
def remove_characters_after_tokenization (tokens):
     pattern = re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
     filtered_tokens = filter(None, [pattern.sub('', token) for token in tokens])
     return filtered_tokens
```

Then I called that function on a list of tokens:

```
tokenList = [tokenize_text(text) for text in corpus]

tokenListCharsRemoved = list([filter(None,
[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens in sentence_token]) for sentence_token in tokenList])

pprint(tokenListCharsRemoved)
```

The results look like this:

```
filter object at 0x000000000F607F98,
filter object at 0x000000000F607C50>,
filter object at 0x000000000F607C18>
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the combination of `filter` and `list` returning a list with the cleaned tokens?

This is not a duplicate of the suggested duplicate question, because I have attempted the solution from that question (as demonstrated by my code). I have also attempted the "".join method as well.

In addition, I just tried this which resulted in the same output:

```
tokenListCharsRemoved = []
for sentence_token in tokenList:
       i = filter(None,[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens in sentence_token])
       tokenListCharsRemoved.append(i)

pprint(list(tokenListCharsRemoved))
```

Comment: You're not calling `list` on the filter objects themselves. You're calling `list` on a list that contains filter objects.

Comment: Change your comprehension to `[list(filter(None,
[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens in sentence_token])) for sentence_token in tokenList])` Note i moved the call to `list` *inside* the comprehension.

Comment: That returns an `invalid syntax` error

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a list before returning.  This will "render" it.

```
return list(filtered_tokens)
```

Comment: This returns the same output as before.

Comment: You'll need to break this up into separate steps.  Don't try to do everything in one line.  Then print out each intermediate value to confirm it is correct.  Rinse, repeat. ;)

Comment: Thank you! I figured out a solution, but I can't post it as an answer because of my reputation. Also, my question keeps getting down voted despite the fact that it's not actually a duplicate. I'm new, and I'm not quite sure how to fix that..

Comment: I think its because the question hasn't been completely separated from your project, there's baggage involved, and SO doesn't appreciate "homework" questions.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I could separate it - it is pretty generic as it is! Definitely not a homework question either. The code is largely from Sarkar's Text Analytics with Python book, but the application is for work.